# Why does the torah repeat itself regarding מומין in Kohanim?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, kohen-priest, parashas-emor

In Emor, [perek:21 posuk:17](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.21.17?lang=bi&aliyot=0) the Torah says:

> דַּבֵּ֥ר אֶֽל־אַהֲרֹ֖ן לֵאמֹ֑ר אִ֣ישׁ מִֽזַּרְעֲךָ֞ לְדֹרֹתָ֗ם אֲשֶׁ֨ר יִהְיֶ֥ה בוֹ֙ מ֔וּם לֹ֣א יִקְרַ֔ב לְהַקְרִ֖יב לֶ֥חֶם אֱלֹהָֽיו׃
>
> Speak to Aaron and say: No man of your offspring throughout the ages
> who has a defect shall be qualified to offer the food of his God.

Then just a few pesukim later ([posuk 21](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.21.21?lang=bi&aliyot=0)), it states:

> כָּל־אִ֞ישׁ אֲשֶׁר־בּ֣וֹ מ֗וּם מִזֶּ֙רַע֙ אַהֲרֹ֣ן הַכֹּהֵ֔ן לֹ֣א יִגַּ֔שׁ לְהַקְרִ֖יב אֶת־אִשֵּׁ֣י יְהוָ֑ה מ֣וּם בּ֔וֹ אֵ֚ת לֶ֣חֶם אֱלֹהָ֔יו לֹ֥א יִגַּ֖שׁ לְהַקְרִֽיב

> "No man among the offspring of Aaron the priest who has a defect shall be qualified to offer the LORD’s offering by fire; having a defect, he shall not be qualified to offer the food of his God."
> (translations by sefaria)

What is behind this repetition?

Comment: Mum's the word.

Answer (score 1):

From [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.21?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Leviticus.21.21&lang2=bi) there:

> כל  איש אשר בו מום. לְרַבּוֹת שְׁאָר מוּמִין:
> NO MAN THAT HATH A BLEMISH… [SHALL COME NEAR] — This is intended to include in the prohibition (besides the blemishes expressly mentioned in vv. 18—20) also other bodily blemishes (Sifra, Emor, Chapter 3 1).
> 2
> מום בו. בְּעוֹד מוּמוֹ בּוֹ פָּסוּל, הָא אִם עָבַר מוּמוֹ כָּשֵׁר (ספרא):
> HE HATH A BLEMISH — These apparently redundant words imply: so long as he has the bodily blemish he is unfit for priestly service; (the translation is: מום בו while the blemish is in him, '‎לא יגש וכו‎ he shall not approach to offer); consequently, if his blemish disappears, he becomes again fit for it (Sifra, Emor, Chapter 3 6).

The commentators explain that "other blemishes" refers to anything that gives the kohen an unusual appearance.

Comment: I should have made it clearer, but my question was why the fact that a kohen with a mum may not serve was repeated, not why in the second posuk quoted it says 'mum' twice. But thank you for the insight anyway.

Comment: Your question is still answered. The Torah often repeats the basic idea to teach new halachos.

Comment: What extra halochos does the first posuk tell us?

Comment: The first posuk makes the second possuk extra, so that the second one is teaching new halachos.